# In R language, how to calculate SD without using formula

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I am trying to calculate sd using formula shew<-(sum((x-kl)^2))/(t-1) but result is wrong. I have tried calculating sd using SD function and result is different. can anyone help.

```
IndexStart <- 1
x <- seq(IndexStart, 6, 1)
x
t<-6
xm <- 1
kl<-mean(x)
kl
n<-sd(x)
n
shew<-(sum((x-kl)^2))/(t-1)
```

Comment: @李哲源 Zheyuan Li is correct , look [formula](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-formulas.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not seem like a typo question so I answer it.

You missed a square root: `sqrt(shew)`, otherwise you get sample variance not standard error.

Comment: It's is giving me this reply. Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.